# Is it possible to create an application to check every opened file on windows?

Tags: c#, c, windows, logging, kernel

I'd like to build an application (if there isn't already one) to log every Windows (7, 64-bit) opened file (including attributes) on C#.

What do you think? Could it be possible? Is there another software already built to do this? Do I Need to use a low-level language (C?) and manage kernel events?

Comment: have a look at filemon or it's replacement processmon: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642 it should do exactly what you need, but is not open source.

Comment: Looks nice! But it show only *.exe opened file, not the attributes of it :( I mean, if I open this `c:/programs/file.exe /my-attributes` how can I catch `/my-attributes`?

Comment: No, procmon will show all open files

Comment: I'm confused just like David i guess. Do you want to monitor open files or do you want to monitor all running process and from those process the arguments supllied during process creation? Your comment suggest the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean, if I open this c:/programs/file.exe /my-attributes how can I catch /my-attributes

What you are really asking for is the *command line* that was used to start a process.  An entirely different problem from trying to discover what *files* are opened by a process.  And one that you can actually do with C#, using System.Management to run a query on the  Win32_Process class.  Start a new console mode project and add a reference to System.Management.  Make the code look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Management;  // NOTE: add a reference to System.Management!

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()) {
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj["CommandLine"]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Beware that the output is not very clean and requires parsing.  Some processes may appear with their internal Windows path (like `\??\etc`), some processes don't have a full path name.  Review the [Win32_Process class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what other properties are available.

Comment: +1 This probably needs to be combined with `ManagementEventWatcher` to  get notifications of processes starting and stopping